# converting a NodeProxy to NodeEntity in spring-data-neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-graph

I have the below Cypher query. It returns a list of players and list of all the leagues played by each player. Now For each of the returned players, I would like to create the `Person` `NodeEntity` instead of using the `NodeProxy`. Wondering what is the efficient way of doing this.

```
String q = "START t=node({teamId}) MATCH player-[:PLAYED_WITH_TEAM]->t-[:CONTESTED_IN]->league WITH player AS player, league.startDate AS startDate, league.name AS leagueName ORDER BY startDate RETURN player,  collect(leagueName) AS leagueNames";

Map<String, Object> params = Maps.newHashMap();
params.put("teamId", selectedTeam);

Result<Map<String, Object>> result = template.query(q, params);

final List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

result.handle(new Handler<Map<String, Object>>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(Map<String, Object> value)
    {       
        players.add((Player) value.get("player"));
    }
});
```

**Exception**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/avl] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy cannot be cast to com.aravind.avl.domain.Player] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy cannot be cast to com.aravind.avl.domain.Player
    at com.aravind.avl.controller.RegistrationController$1.handle(RegistrationController.java:103)
```

Comment: are you in a transactional context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud use the *convert* method from the  *Neo4jOperations* interface to convert the returned object to its proper class; this is an example:

```
neo4jOperations.convert(value.get("player"), Player.class);
```

The *neo4jOperations* object is injected by the Spring Data Neo4j infrastructure using the *@Autowired* annotation.

Comment: neo4jOperations is not being injecting,it is null in my service.

Comment: How it can be achieved in SDN 4 ?

Comment: As of SDN 4 Neo4jOperations has been deprecated, read through [paragraph 11.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#_query_methods) in the SDN 4 documentation to understand how to collect query results.